# Wrong sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select:

```
SELECT

            oa.einheit,
            op.id, op.artikelnummer,
            op.preis_pro_einheit, op.p1_einheit, op.p2_einheit, op.p3_einheit, op.zusatztext, op.position,
            oa.artikel, oa.beschreibung, oa.einheit, oa.anzahl_parameter, oa.su_gewerk, oa.mbs_artikel,
            oa.mindermenge_kleiner_als, oa.zulage_mindermengen_artikel_nummer,
            ae.p1_einheit AS p1_einheit_description,
            ae.p2_einheit AS p2_einheit_description,
            ae.p3_einheit AS p3_einheit_description
        FROM
            objekt_position op
        INNER JOIN objekt_artikel oa
                ON oa.artikelnummer = op.artikelnummer 
               AND oa.id_objekt = op.id_objekt 
               AND oa.id_subunternehmer = op.id_subunternehmer
        INNER JOIN artikel_einheit ae
                ON ae.bezeichnung = oa.einheit
        INNER JOIN subunternehmer s
                ON s.subunternehmernummer = op.id_subunternehmer
        INNER JOIN subunternehmer_user su
                ON su.id_subunternehmer = s.subunternehmernummer
        WHERE
            su.id_user = 1
        AND
            op.id_objekt = 1486598
        AND
            oa.artikelnummer = 172
        GROUP BY op.id
        ORDER BY
            op.position
```

but it seems that my inner join objekt_artikel are not working. what should i change? because i didnt get a result. But there are results in the table.

Comment: You should consider your filters, if no record abiding to the filters, its normal not to have any outputs!

Comment: what means "are not working" provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: I would suggest turning all your inner joins to Left joins and then start one by one start to turning them back to inner joins. Whenever your don't get your expected results then that's where you are missing your join condition.

Comment: Most often this problem occurs due to a NULL in a column you are joining on (missing default/not null constraint)